# Implement single log in with opensaml in java

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

I would implement single signing with opensaml library, but don't know which parameter i will pass for log in. So can any body help for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The sign on starts with sending a XML message called a AutnRequest to the identity provider. SAML authentication is quite complex so I would suggest reading up on the process. The [SAML technical overview](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf) is a good start.

When you are ready to start looking at OpenSAML my book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), gives a good introduction and step by step on SAML and the OpenSAML library.

Also my blog has a couple of examples on this.
https://blog.samlsecurity.com/categories/opensaml/
https://blog.samlsecurity.com/categories/saml/

Comment: I complete almost all code but don't know how to pass SAMLRequest with username and password for authentication and I know about OpenSAML. Also I made up AuthnRequest for login.

Comment: You dont, what you do is, you redirect the user to the IDP with a AuthnRequest let the user write the username and password.

Comment: @StefanRasmusson If the authorization is required to be carried out by SOAP say SP is SOAP API, in this case how we can authorize with IDP?

Comment: Then your SOAP API need to integrate with the IDP to validate the SAML assertion. How this is done is different depending on the solution you use. I suggest you create a new question with more detail and specify that it is about saml authentication for webservices.